# Cloud Dataflow 429 errors - "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)."

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

One of our jobs started throwing up the following warning/error:

```
856573 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob  - There were problems getting current job status: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.getState(DataflowPipelineJob.java:188)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob.waitToFinish(DataflowPipelineJob.java:126)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:86)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.run(BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.tls.cdf.job.AbstractCloudDataFlowJob.execute(AbstractCloudDataFlowJob.java:100)
    at com.tls.cdf.CloudDataFlowJobExecutor.main(CloudDataFlowJobExecutor.java:44)
```

At first we though this was an error allocating the desired resources (VM's) for the job, but in fact the job ran fine and it was able to scale up as needed. It seems to be when trying to retrieve the job status is the problem.

Interestingly, each time the error was thrown in the application (there were multiple reported while the job ran), the developer console would also bork with this:

[image]

The job id is: **2015-05-04_20_49_53-2521857061976321751**

What is this warning/error related to?

Comment: Kicked the job off again. Same warn/error. Job ID: 2015-05-04_22_24_18-14315181703270116638

Comment: Happened to me too today.

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue on our end reporting monitoring information. We've rolled back the change, and you should be good now. Please let us know if you're still having issues. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Errors are gone now. Good job!

Comment: Errors have reappeared, but now they are 503's - "The service is currently unavailable":  441910 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob  - There were problems getting current job status: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
  "status" : "UNAVAILABLE"
}